# How to pass arguments to /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, cocoa, unix, terminal, nstask

In my terminal, I do
`$ myprogram myfile.ext`.

I want to be able to do the same via the command `/bin/bash`, but it is not working.

I tried

```
$ /bin/bash -c -l myprogram myfile.ext
```

but it is not working. It seems that `my program` is launched but without my `file.ext` as an option (as an input file)

Does anyone has a clue on how to do that?

---

### Why I ask this question

I want to launch `myprogram` via `NSTask` in an a program I am writing for `OSX`, with the `cocoa` framework. If I simply ask `NSTask` to launch my program, it seems that some `variable environment` are missing. So, what I try is to launch a shell and inside this shell to launch `myprogram`.

Comment: Please give the full context of what you're trying to do including any environment conditions that make this a special case. Based on your comments to answers this is not just a case of invoking bash with a filename to run.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `-c` altogether. From the manpage:

```
bash [options] [file]
…
Bash  is  an  sh-compatible command language interpreter that executes commands read from the standard input or from a file.
```

Thus, you can execute your program via

```
bash myprogram myfile.ext
```

and `myfile.ext` will be the first positional parameter.

```
bash -l myprogram myfile.ext
```

will work as well, (but whether or not bash is invoked as a login shell seems tangential to this question.)

Answer (score 1):

```
-c string 
    If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from
    string.  If there are arguments after the  string,  they  are
    assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

You need to quote the command passed in as string so it's treated as a single argument for the `-c` option, which then gets executed normally with the argument following the command, i.e.

```
/bin/bash -c -l 'myprogram myfile.ext'
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is working if I type this command in a terminal. But, if if try to execute it via `fork()` or `exec()`it is not working... Any idea?

Comment: The error I get is `/bin/bash: myprogarm  myfile.ext No such file or directory` whereas `/bin/bash -c -l 'myprogram'` works.

Comment: @Colas Try providing the full path to `myprogarm`

Comment: I tried too, but the result is the same. :(

Comment: @Colas Can you show the full `exec` or `fork` you're trying?

Comment: I try to launch `pdflatex` via `cocoa`. It is `/bin/bash -l -c '/usr/texbin/pdflatex myfile.tex'`. I launch it via `NSTask`.

Comment: @Colas Haven't used `NSTask`, but are you sure you have correct quoting within it? The `bash` command looks fine, though I would provide the full path to `myfile.tex` as well depending on where it's located.

Comment: Good idea, but even with the full path of `myfile.tex` it is nor working :(